# Rails Database Nested Search Confusion

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a nested search, and, while it always returns the correct information, it's returning three copies of each entry!!

I want to search my users based on their username, their first name, a hobby, or a type of hobby. Every user has zero, one, or many hobbies.

This is my query:

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    joins(:hobbies)
      .where("user_name like ? or first_name like ? or hobbies.name like ? or hobbies.type like ?", query, query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

If I search by hobby name or hobby type, I get the correct response.

But if I search by username or first name, I get three clones of the same entry!! Why does it do that??

Comment: What result you get when you use `includes` instead of `joins` ?

Comment: Well that worked. But how come?

Comment: `includes` does a Left Out Join , so for every matching condition only one row will be returned as result. I have extended it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `includes` instead of `joins` .

`includes` makes a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** whereas `joins` makes an **INNER JOIN**.