# Railed Database Nested Search Confusion: part 2

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

A while back I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731666/rails-database-nested-search-confusion?noredirect=1#comment66773679_39731666).

This is my query:

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    joins(:hobbies)
      .where("user_name like ? or first_name like ? or hobbies.name like ? or hobbies.type like ?", query, query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

However, I now have a SECOND nested attribute that I want to search by -- games!

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    joins(:hobbies)
    joins(:games)
      .where("user_name like ? or first_name like ? or hobbies.name like ? or hobbies.type like ? or games.number like ?", query, query, query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work. How exactly do I join them all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dot.

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    joins(:hobbies)
    .joins(:games)
      .where("user_name like ? or first_name like ? or hobbies.name like ? or hobbies.type like ? or games.number like ?", query, query, query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

The better way to write this is

```
def self.search(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    joins(:hobbies, :games)
      .where("user_name like ? or first_name like ? or hobbies.name like ? or hobbies.type like ? or games.number like ?", query, query, query, query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow that was simple! Thks!